# Android - cant add button to Actionbar

Tags: android, xml, menu, android-actionbar

I am trying to add a button to my action bar in android

Below is my code in the menu/main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_compose"
    android:icon="@drawable/help"
    android:title="help"/>

</menu>
```

and I added this to my Activity

```
@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }
```

But when I run the app the Actionbar is still the same, I'm not sure if it matters but I have a Navigation drawer in my app to.

Comment: Try add `android:showAsAction="always"` to the items and see if something happens?

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherlock or the Android Support library?

Comment: try with custom actionbar sherlock. then its easy to add button or anything... before that add sherlock library in your project.

Comment: Does setting `android:showAsAction` worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

use actionbar sherlock library and use below code.

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements TabListener 
{

ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.issue240);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setCustomView(YOUR_BUTTON_LAYOUT);
      }
 }
```